# How do I use VBA to choose a range depending on what's in another range?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to figure out VBA and Excel and I've ran into some problems. I'm trying to select a range, and depending on if another column(P) is empty, I'll choose either column N or M to select.

Basically I've tried something like this without success.

```
IF(P7="",Range("N7").Select , Range("M7").Select)
```

So in pseudo code:

> IF P7 is empty DO N7.Select ELSE M7.Select

Am I anywhere near a solution here?

Answer (score 1):

What you've given is a formula. VBA doesn't use formula syntax like we would enter into a cell.

You will need to use the `IF...[condition]...THEN...[do this]...ELSE...[do this]` with a check for `Null`, which is how Excel looks to see the cell is empty.

```
If Range("P7").Value = Null Then
    Range("N7").Select
Else
    Range("M7").Select
End If
```

Here is more information about [Getting Started with VBA in Excel 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question, feel free to mark it as such.